# Is this even Possible to do using BLE and smartphone APP

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've an idea for an App but not sure if it's actually possible to do, any help or advice would be most appreciated.

I would like my APP (BLEAPPX) to open Bluetooth, then list other BLE devices it can 'see' within range. The list would be filtered to ONLY include other devices that had the same BLEAPPX loaded on its device. Is this possible to 'know' that the device has the APP loaded?

I would then like to be able to tap on one of these devices in the list - and assuming the other device does have the same BLEAPPX loaded, to be able to send a request - and have the other device pass back some data - maybe the owners name or App id. In effect - say Hi to someone who also has the same APP loaded and find out who they are.

Can this be done without having to ask the other device to allow Pairing to take place?

Thanks for any help

Phil

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just advertise a custom service, and when you perform your BLE scan, filter on this service.

Comment: Thank you for response Emil